# Sharing small data using Windows shared memory

Tags: c++, c, winapi, ipc, shared-memory

I'm looking for advice and suggestions for storing small amounts of data (only a few bytes) in a shared memory segment on Windows.

Right now, whenever we map shared memory, we round the mapping size up to the nearest 4KB so we get a multiple of pages mapped.

```
mem_size = ((mem_size + 4095) / 4096) * 4096;
```

However, I want to map enough memory to share a named integer between processes. Or more specifically, many differently-named integers between processes. About a thousand integers, all with different names and each one mapped by one or more processes is what I'm looking at.

I don't want to round 4 bytes up to 4KB because this would be a huge waste. After creating a thousand or so of these, I would have used about a thousand pages when I only needed one.

But I am worried about the overhead of creating a named memory segment for just 4 bytes. Will the OS be "reasonable" enough to try and fit the different mappings onto the same page where possible? (There are no guarantees, I know). Or will this quickly blow out?

I had considered mapping one huge block of memory, but the individual integers still need to be referred to by name. Maintaining a hash table inside shared memory seems like I'd just be duplicating the work of the OS.

Is there an alternative to the `CreateFileMapping/OpenFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile` technique that would be more suited to sharing very small amounts of data between processes? Or am I worrying over nothing?

Comment: How many integers (roughly) are you talking about?

Comment: @JonathanPotter A rough estimate would be about 1000, all with different names. Each one would be mapped by one or more processes.

Comment: If you don't want to duplicate/implement your own hash system about all I can think of is using `GlobalAddAtom()` to get an atom for each name, maintaining one block of data as a map of atoms->indices, and another block of data to store the actual data. This isn't ideal though as it would require a linear search of the atom map to convert an atom to an index.

Comment: Another idea I just had is to create a singleton window that maintains the integers using `SetProp()`/`GetProp()`. I'm not sure if `GetProp()` works cross-process or not, but if it does you could just read the integers directly by finding the window handle and calling `GetProp()`. If it doesn't work cross-process you could still do this by sending the window a message and having it return the result of the `GetProp()` call. The only downside is performance , as this would certainly be slower than accessing shared memory directly.

Comment: And actually, if you're doing it via `SendMessage()` then you don't even need to use window properties - you could use a `std::map`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I forgot all about `ATOM`s! They are great, because it's a built-in shared hash table. No development required there! You get 0xFFFF different possible values (way more than I need). So I map 0xFFFF * sizeof(int) into memory, then use the global atom table to get me the index into that mapped memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this in 8K.  The first 4k block is a binary table (or a hash table) for the integer name and its offset in the second 4k block.  When adding a new name, you will need to serialize, and when retrieving a name/offset, block on that serialization.

After a process has retrieved its name/offset it can then go directly to the second block and avoid any serialization!  This will be a logic path that is taken more than 90% (probably) of the time.  Thus your code should run very efficiently with minimal overhead.

The second 4k block will hold 1,000 `int`s (in windows anyway!).  Each integer would **NOT** affect the others, so this design is "thread safe".  However, if the processes do a lot (where a lot is every process updates about every 1ms, so that two processes are always in contention to write to the file) of updating to this common file, and the complete file has to be serialized (rather than implicitly because no two processes share the same integer name) when updating in place then you could end-up with a bottleneck.

the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366801%28v=vs.85%29.aspx describes how to update the shared memory.  If each process has its own integer "slot" then there shouldn't be any contention.

I don't think a name tree or hash table is duplicating the OS.

Finally, this seems like a medium skill project and should be relatively easy to maintain!

Comment: As long as no two names hash to the same value.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, **not** true.  A hash table places a name into a bucket or head of list pointer that is then sequentially searched for an exact match.  The point of a hash table is that there is an O(k) hash and then a second O(n/nr_bins) search of a sequential list that is a very small fraction of n.

Comment: I know what a hash table is, but what you were describing doesn't sound like it uses buckets, but relies on a direct 1:1 relationship between the name and the index in the table. I'm not sure you could do it in 4Kb, but if you can - great :)

Comment: @JonathanPotter, even if the hash table had to be over two pages (8k) and the integer in one page, that is still just 12k or lets even say (16k) if more than 1,000 integers.  Small enough to not affect system performance.

Comment: I have used this idea, along with Jonathan Potter's idea to use the global ATOM table. This way, I can use a provided solution as the hash table. The index into the shared integer array is just `(Atom - MAXINTATOM)`.

Comment: @anthony-arnold, this method is fine, just be aware that the atom values are **NOT** sequential.  they just range from xc000 to xffff, which is 32k?  So, the common file will have to be 32k.  Which is **not** a big deal on these 2gb, etc. paging systems.

Comment: @JackCColeman Yes, it's fine. Actually, the range 0xC000 - 0xFFFF is just around 16k, if you rebase 0xC000 to zero. I end up with way more than the 1000 I need, but for memory usage on a modern system (not embedded) it's a pittance.

Comment: @anthony-arnold, be sure to account for the fact that integers are 4 or 2 bytes.  Thus, the atom gives a number but that number must be multiplied by 2 or 4 to get the correct offset.

Comment: @anthony-arnold, so what is really happening is that you will allocate anywhere from 32k to 128k (0xffff - 0xc000 = 0x3ff = 0x10000 - 1 = 2^13 - 1) in order to store 1k of values!  Rethink, how to build the string table.  It depends on reference patterns: how often is a string added, how often referenced directly or using the string name?  Sometimes a simple array that is binary searched is sufficient, or b-tree!  Hashing works when majority of accesses is by string name.  Also, scale your system.  If possible, start with 10 processes using this new method, test, debug, etc. then 100, 500, etc

Comment: I'm not really that keen to write a shared-memory hash table or b-tree (I've done something quite similar before; not as easy as it sounds) just so save around 127k.

Comment: @anthony-arnold, coding is a risk, and for a task at work probably not want you want to do.  However, the more or longer you take to code something, the less risk.  So, being able to save 127k of common storage would be a good back-up plan, this allows you to do the simple solution first, work on the second as time permits and then only use it if necessary, and along the way you have coded ONE MORE medium difficulty problem which is always good!  (consider a linked list if there are only one time adds, and few (once every minute) look-ups by name).  A ll is easier than a ht and can be as good.

Answer (score 1):

A shared memory segment on x86 processeors can't be smaller than 4096 bytes. Shared memory is handled by the mmu on the processor, which organizes everything in 4096 bytes large pages.